# What these symbols on profile of a cycling stage mean?

Tags: cycling

I have looked on profile of today's stage of Tour de Suisse:

[image]

(The picture is taken from http://www.procyclingstats.com/races/profilesmaps/2014-06/Tour-de-Suisse-Stage-6-1403118873.png.)

There are three little blue symbols at the bottom. I suppose the middle one, with the cutlery, means [feed zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_cycling#F). However, I was not able to guess the meaning of the symbols [image] and [image], which seem somewhat like light bulb or a bottle.

Comment: Found a more detailed document including the photo above, but without much insight toward what those symbols mean: http://www.tourdesuisse.ch/fileadmin/user_upload/2014/Etappenplan/Marschtabellen/MT_6_Etappe_final.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing [edmastermind29's comment](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4993/what-these-symbols-on-profile-of-a-cycling-stage-mean#comment11461_4993) I have tried looking for more documents on the [website of the race](http://www.tourdesuisse.ch/). In the section [media](http://www.tourdesuisse.ch/en/media/) I have found [technical guide](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3t995gaui7qzjw1/HD_Technischer_Guide_TourDeSuisse_2014_PDF_HD_Web.pdf), which also gives explanations of these symbols (and some other symbols used in the maps and plans of stages). I only found the explanation in German and French language.

[image]

So the two symbols I was asking about mark where it is allowed to get food from the team cars. (According to [UCI Cycling Regulation](http://www.uci.ch/includes/asp/getTarget.asp?type=FILE&id=OTU2MDE): *Feeding is prohibited on climbs, descents and during the first 50 and last 20 km.* (2.3.027))

Comment: It is avoided to feed your cyclists from your car in order to ward off danger when the race get carried away (beginning of breakaways and next to finish line).

Comment: +1 It would have been nicer to have a legend right away (instead of digging up this information), but nonetheless, great work!! :)